# Set the pop-up menu inside a grid, but pull it out of the edges when called up

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

I create a pop-up menu via pancakeview and then the expander.
The procedure I see that works, but the menu, due to the borders of the grid, is not displayed at all.
Solutions?`

```
<pv:PancakeView HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7">
                    <pv:PancakeView.BackgroundGradientStops>
                        <pv:GradientStopCollection>
                        </pv:GradientStopCollection>
                    </pv:PancakeView.BackgroundGradientStops>
                    <behaviors:Expander HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="End" Rotation="180" BackgroundColor="White">
                        <behaviors:Expander.Header>
                            <Image Source="altro.png" x:Name="imgAltro" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Image.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type behaviors:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                 Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="altroArancione.png" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Image.Triggers>
                            </Image>
                        </behaviors:Expander.Header>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <ImageButton Source="dashboard.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Rotation="180" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                            <ImageButton Source="anagrafica.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Rotation="180" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </behaviors:Expander>
                    </pv:PancakeView>
```

[image]

[image]

this is the table setting:

```
<Grid Margin="0" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: If you don't want it limited by the grid, then why put it inside the grid? Show the surrounding XAML - is this all in a ContentPage? Maybe what you want is the outer-most layout to be a grid, and then inside that, OVERLAY the pop-up menu and your existing grid. As two independent elements, both with Grid.Row=0, Grid.Column=0.

Comment: I put it inside the grid to position it, I made a horizontal menu at the bottom of the page

Comment: *"I put it inside the grid to position it"* I understand. So instead, put both the grid and the menu inside another grid, laid on top of each other (both in the same cell of the outer grid).

Answer (score 0):

To position two items, but let one overlay the other, put them both inside another grid:

Approach #1: A "single cell" outer grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid ...your-grid-options... >
        <Label Text="Your grid contents" FontSize="40"/>
    </Grid>
    <Label VerticalOptions="End" Text="This is the menu at bottom" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
</Grid>
```

- `VerticalOptions="End"` forces the menu to the bottom. In other situations, `Margin` or `Padding` values might be helpful.

(When layouts are nested, "outer" (aka "topmost"; "outside") means the first one in the XAML, "inner" is the nested (inside; indented) one.)

---

Approach #2: A two-row outer grid. Overkill for this use, but showing how `RowSpan` can help in more complex overlay cases:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="*,40" RowSpacing="0">
    <!-- Use RowSpan 2 if inner grid should extend under menu area. -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ...your-grid-options... >
        <Label Text="Your grid contents" FontSize="40"/>
    </Grid>
    <Label Grid.Row="1"  VerticalOptions="End" Text="This is the menu at bottom" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
</Grid>
```

- Force menu to bottom by putting it in second row of outer grid and/or using `VerticalOptions="End"`. Here, I've done BOTH techniques.
- Row 0's height is "*"; it is given all space not used by Row 1.
- I show Row 1's height as "40"; change value as needed. Depending on what you put in that row, "Auto" might also work.
- If want to leave a gap at bottom of grid, where menu will appear, remove `Grid.RowSpan="2"`.